# laravel real time data retrieve from database

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

how can i have real time data in laravel?

## logic

i have JavaScript based form for saving new data in my database and it's working

beside my saving data form i have select box which contains my saved data to select.

the issue is in my select box i only see my older data and if i want to see data that i saved just now i must refresh the page.

## example:

i save new specification in my database let say `core i5 cpu` then beside my form i have select box to select specifications in that box i cannot see `core i5 cpu` i must refresh the page to see it.

## question

how can i have my result as soon as it saved to database without refreshing the page?

> ps: what i need is idea of how to retrieve my `specifications` without
>   refereshing the page.

*should i convert my data to json and retrieve it by ajax or how?*

## UPDATE

I have added new function and route in order to get my data as json in ajax, here is what i have now:

`controller`

```
public function subspacs(){
      $specifications = Specification::with('subspecifications')->get();
      return response()->json($specifications); 
}
```

`route`

```
Route::get('subspacs', 'ProductController@subspacs')->name('subspacs');
```

`javascript`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
             type:"GET",
             url:"{{ url('admin/subspacs') }}",
             success : function(response) {
              console.log(response);
             }
        }); 
  });  
</script>
```

#### Issues

1. my Ajax will show my data in console `but not updated data`, **the issue
   of seeing new data requires refreshing the page still remains.**
2. I tried code below in order to `refresh my select box every 2 seconds`
   by jQuery and that works.

   `setTimeout ( function ( ) {
     $ ( ' #subspecifications ') . append ('< option value = "gg" >TEST SUCCESS< / option> ');
   } , 2000 ) ;`

basically i have tried 2 ways and unsuccessful results:

1. using Ajax (didn't work as expected)
2. trying to refresh my select box result (worked)

**Now the `question` is how do I put added specification under their parents in select box?**

## screen capture

[here is small video](https://streamable.com/a4qeb) to see what exactly going on at the moment and avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Check [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting)

Comment: Ajax should definitely help you. Create an action to retrieve data from DB. Call it with Ajax in javascript.

Comment: @anil_pulikoden would you mind help me to get my data with ajax? i have made `public function subspacs(){$specifications = Specification::all();return response()->json($specifications); }` and route `Route::get('subspacs','ProductController@subspacs')->name('subspacs');` how do i show them in blade?

Comment: @anil_pulikoden updated my question

Comment: @devk updated my question

Comment: If I well understood, you're sending requests to the server every 2 secs to check if data has been updated, right?

Comment: @Brigo yes.....

Comment: @mafortis Well, that's not a good idea; especially in large application, doing so would kill the app. The best is to listen the server for new updates. See [EventSource API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) and, as devk pointed out, [Laravel Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting)

Comment: @brigo i am using broadcast for pusher I'm not sure if I can set 2 different broadcaster in env file, that's why I'm seeking another solution such as using ajax or reload my data each of them that can handle my need is fine by me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax

```
$.ajax({
              type:'GET',
              url:'{{ url("/getpost") }}',
              data: {data from response}
              success:function(response){
                console.log(response);              
              },
              error:function(){console.log(data);}
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

I added button to my view:

```
<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Refresh" id="customerSearchButton" class="btn-sm btn btn-warning customerSearchButton" type="button"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
```

and changed my script to:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#customerSearchButton").on("click", function (event) {
      $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
          url: "{{ url('admin/subspacs') }}",
          type: "GET",
        }).success(function (result) {
            $('#subspecifications').empty();
            // loop
            $.each(result, function(key, value) {
              $('#subspecifications').append('<optgroup label="'+value.title+'"></optgroup>');
                $.each(value.subspecifications, function(key2, value2) {
                  $('#subspecifications').append('<option value="'+value2['id']+'">'+value2['title']+'</option>');
                });
            });
            // end loop
          })
    });
  });  
</script>
```

now each time I hit the button my specification list will be updated with latest data.

hope it helps.